# d3js plotting linecharts undefined is not iterable

Tags: d3.js, linechart

I'm learning `d3js` and I need help in creating line charts. I'm fairly successful plotting simple objects and bar charts. Line charts seems to be a steep hill to climb.

```js
const data = [{
    "LINE1": [
      10,
      11,
      12,
      15
    ]
  },
  {
    "LINE2": [
      21,
      22,
      23,
      32
    ]
  },
  {
    "LINE3": [
      11,
      12,
      13,
      15
    ]
  }
]

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {
    top: 50,
    right: 100,
    bottom: 130,
    left: 120
  },
  width = 900 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("#ca")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);

// Add X axis
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain(d3.extent(data, (d) => d.length))
  .range([0, width]);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(5));

// Add Y axis
// I need help in this area, how can I get the min and max values set in the domain?
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, (d) => d.values)])
  .range([height, 0]);

svg.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

// Draw the line
// I need help in this area, how can I get the lines plotted, js gives error in this!
svg.selectAll(".line")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "black")
  .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
  .attr("d", (d) => {
    console.log(d)
    var k = d3.line()
      .x((d) => x(d))
      .y((d) => y(d))
      (d.values);
    console.log(k);
    return k;
  });
```

```html
<div id="ca">
</div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
```

How can I get the line charts plotted with data format I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made your example work, but there are several things you need to know here:

1. Your data structure was very chaotic. If you want to have an array of objects as data, make sure all objects have the same keys. It's fine if you use `[{y: [...]}, {y: [...]}]`, but `[{LINE1: [...]}, {LINE2: [...]}]` is very difficult to work with. I changed your data to be more like `[[...], [...], [...]]` as a structure.
2. Don't create a separate `d3.line` for every line, just create it once and call it. It's a line factory, which means it is a function that, when called, returns a line. If it's not shared, it might use different domains and ranges, making the chart difficult or even useless.
3. If the first argument in a function is `d`, the second is `i`, the index of the node in the array. In this case, you use that to start at `x=0`, and go to `x=3`. You used `d` to try to get that value.
4. Keep in mind the structure of your data. You kept wanting to access `d.values`, but that never existed!

```js
const data = Object.values({
  "LINE1": [
    10,
    11,
    12,
    15
  ],
  "LINE2": [
    21,
    22,
    23,
    32
  ],
  "LINE3": [
    11,
    12,
    13,
    15
  ]
});

var line = d3.line()
  .x((d, i) => x(i))
  .y((d) => y(d));

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {
    top: 50,
    right: 100,
    bottom: 130,
    left: 120
  },
  width = 900 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("#ca")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);

// Add X axis
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, (d) => d.length)])
  .range([0, width]);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(5));

// Add Y axis
// I need help in this area, how can I get the min and max values set in the domain?
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, (d) => Math.max(...d))])
  .range([height, 0]);

svg.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

// Draw the line
// I need help in this area, how can I get the lines plotted, js gives error in this!
svg.selectAll(".line")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "black")
  .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
  .attr("d", (d) => line(d));
```

```html
<div id="ca">
</div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
```